# Only last line of output gets saved

Tags: python

I am new to handling files (new to python overall) and I have been given a task to write a function that does some math, then write a program that takes some numbers from a file and does said math from the function to those numbers. (confusing I know.)

Now, that's all done. The problem is I have to now create a new file and save the output from those equations into a new file, and I keep getting only the last line. When i print "results", it prints out all of the output like it should, but when I try to save it into a new file.. disaster strikes. I tried doing a for loop, but it also gives the same result. If anyone can lend me hand and tell me what I should do I'd be thankful.

```
import math as m

def solve(a, b, c):
d = b**2 - 4*a*c
d = m.sqrt(d)
x1 = (-b + d) / (2 * a)
x2 = (-b - d) / (2 * a)
return x1, x2

with open("equations.txt", "r") as f:
    for x in f:
        i = x.split()
    
        a, b, c = [float(i[0]), float(i[1]), float(i[2])]
    
        try:
            x1, x2 = solve(a, b, c)
            print(f"{x1=} {x2=}")
        except ValueError:
            print("You can't do the equations on these numbers.")
    
        results = (f"{x1=} {x2=}")
        with open("equations_results.txt", "w") as data:
            data.write(results)
```

Comment: By the way, there seems to be an indentation issue in your question

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is with where you put this stanza:

```
with open('equations_results.txt', 'w') as data:
    data.write(results)
```

You want to put that outside your for loop. What is happening now is that you are opening the file anew and then writing the results out to that file for each `x in f`. But because you are not appending, it simply is overwriting that data.

```
with open('equations.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('equations_results.txt', 'w') as data:
        for x in f:
            ...
            data.write(results)
```

As noted by commentor Fred Larson, you can combine the `with open()` statements like so:

```
source = "equations.txt"
dest = "equation_results.txt"
with open(source, 'r') as f, open(dest, 'w') as data:
    for x in f:
        ...
        data.write(results)
```

Alternatively, if opening them at the same time isn't an option, you can use the 'append' mode:

```
with open('equations.txt', 'r') as f:
    for x in f:
        ...
        with open('equations_results.txt', 'a') as data:
            data.write(results)
```

This latter case still opens the file every iteration, but rather than overwrite/rewrite the file, it only adds to the end of it. This is similar to keeping the file open and writing to it as you go.

Answer (score -1):

```
import math as m

def solve(a, b, c):
    d = b**2 - 4*a*c
    if d < 0:
        return "No solutions" # <-- unless you want complex roots ?
    d = m.sqrt(d)
    x1 = (-b + d) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - d) / (2 * a)
    return str([x1, x2])

with open('equations.txt', 'r') as f:
    
    x = f.readlines()[0].split()
    arr = [float(i) for i in x] # <--- List comp
    a,b,c = arr

    res = solve(a,b,c)
    print(res)

with open('equations_results.txt', 'w') as data:
    data.write(res)
```

The code above should work for ya. You had a problem with you're string with can`'`t, that messes with a string that is defined by `'`. I also changed your logic to calculate when there will be no solutions (when the discriminate (b^2-4ac) is negative.

I also had to assume what your input file is like so I just slapped some numbers together in a file like 
`-11 2 3`

Comment: the "can't" was a mishap in editing the post tbh, it was originally written in my own language and i decided to change it to english. so that wasn't a problem at all haha. thank you sm for the code, it's v helpful!

Comment: Two things: the single quote issue is best fixed by using the standard double quoting rather than eschewing single quotes altogether. Secondly, at the point you write `res` you may not have a `res`. The notion of `with ...` is to wrap a call that needs cleanup, but if there is an issue you could exit that stanza without having assigned anything to `result`. This could then continue on with your next `with open()` and /then/ error. I don't like that this is the one place Python ignores the indentation-scope rules, but if you want to program defensively you should properly next the with opens.